# How should I use this iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, networkx

i've already built a graph and i downloaded this code about Bron–Kerbosch algorithm for finding all maximal cliques in graph, but i don't know how to use it.
code downloaded from here: https://github.com/donfaq/max_clique

```
import networkx as nx
def bronk(graph, P, R=set(), X=set()):
    '''
    Implementation of Bron–Kerbosch algorithm for finding all maximal cliques in graph
    '''
    if not any((P, X)):
        #print(R)
        yield R
    for node in P.copy():
        for r in bronk(graph, P.intersection(graph.neighbors(node)),
                       R=R.union(node), X=X.intersection(graph.neighbors(node))):
            yield r
        P.remove(node)
        X.add(node)
```

Comment: Start by saying where you downloaded the code from

Comment: downloaded from here: https://github.com/donfaq/max_clique

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `graph`, you can run the [Bron–Kerbosch algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bron%E2%80%93Kerbosch_algorithm) and get the maximal cliques:

```py
for max_clique in bronk(graph, set(graph.nodes)):
    print(max_clique)
```